# Access parse current user from Apple Watch

Tags: parse-platform, apple-watch

I am making an application for the Apple Watch.

I successfully linked my watch extension to parse. However, I can't access parse data stored on the phone.(In my case PFUser.currentuser() )

What would be the best way to get my current user?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Parse SDK 1.7.2 is out right now and I feel this is exactly what you are looking for.
It brings full support for sharing data with App Extensions and Apple Watch Apps.

Read more in this blog post http://blog.parse.com/announcements/introducing-local-data-sharing-for-apple-watch-and-app-extensions/

Or in the docs on how to set it up: https://parse.com/docs/ios_guide#extensions/iOS

Comment: It has been deprecated